# I cannot update DATETIME in SQL from Java but the insert works fine

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So here is my code

```
java.sql.Timestamp date = 
        new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
         new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");

String currentTime = sdf.format(date)

int abs=0;
Statement tgl = connect.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = tgl.executeQuery("SELECT id_absensi FROM absensi ORDER BY id_absensi DESC LIMIT 1");
   while (rs.next()){
       abs=rs.getInt("id_absensi");
   }
String query = "UPDATE   absensi  SET tgl_keluar ="
        + currentTime
        + " WHERE  'id_absensi'=" + abs ;
Statement aa = connect.createStatement();
int bb = aa.executeUpdate(query);
```

the problem is that when I try to run this I get this notification

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '01:59:35
>   WHERE  'id_absensi'=1' at line 1

I know it's supposed to be a simple syntax error but I don't know which one? I even tried to copy the actual mysql statement for update
PS. the Select is not the problem, just the update.

Please help

Comment: You should be using `preparedStatements` for one...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need single quotes around `id_absensi` in your INSERT query. You should also use `PreparedStatement` and set `Timestamp date` as a query parameter as follows:

```
String query = "UPDATE absensi SET tgl_keluar=?  WHERE id_absensi=?";
PreparedStatement aa = connect.prepareStatement(query);
aa.setTimestamp(1, date);
aa.setInt(2, abs);
int bb = aa.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Tried it, but still get the same result

Comment: Can you re-post your updated code and error message? If you tried it, at least you wouldn't see `WHERE 'id_absensi'=1' ` because there shouldn't be single quotes around `id_absensi`

Answer (score 0):

for update statement, you should use [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))

and commit

Answer (score -2):

```
String query = "UPDATE absensi SET tgl_keluar = '" + currentTime + "' WHERE 'id_absensi' = " + abs;
```